# vector list initializer and assignment

Tags: c++, initialization

For the two snippet of code, i don't understand the second one

1st: it prints 0 1 2 as expected

```
  vector<int> ivec;
  ivec={0,1,2};
  for(auto i: ivec){
    cout<<ivec[i]<<endl;
  }
```

2nd: it prints 0 0 0 5. How is this random value generated?

```
  vector<int> ivec;
  ivec={0,1,2};
  ivec={4,5,9,1};
  for(auto i: ivec){
    cout<<ivec[i]<<endl;
  }
```

Comment: Ah, so the issue is "range-based-for-loop" versus ```for(int i = 0; i < ivec.size(); i++```.  in your case ```i``` has the values and you can just print ```i``` instead of ```ivec[i]```

Comment: `ivec[0]` is not the same (in general) than `ivec[ivec[0]]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is undefined behavior because `ivec` has size `4` yet you are indexing elements such as `4`, `5`, and `9` which are out of bounds.

```
for(auto i : ivec){
  cout << ivec[i] << endl;
}
```

Instead you should be printing the elements themselves

```
for(auto i : ivec){
  cout << i << endl;
}
```

To be clear, in your range-based `for` loop `i` is the actual element *not* the index of the element. If you wanted to use indices you would not use a range-based `for` loop

```
for(std::size_t i = 0; i < ivec.size(); ++i){
  cout << ivec[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: oh, oops. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this loop here:

```
for(auto i : ivec)
```

is not the same as

```
for(int i =0; ...)
```

when you do

```
for(auto i: ivec){ // with ivec value to {4,5,9,1};
   cout<<ivec[i]<<endl;
}
```

then you do:

```
 cout << ivec[4] << endl; // Undefined Behav...
 cout << ivec[5] << endl; // Undefined Behav...
 cout << ivec[9] << endl; // Undefined Behav...
```